# Flutter Navigator pop and async multiple fields data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i have two text controllers, i want to pass data of both text controllers to home screen from second page, right now my code is working fine with one variable, but how i can pass multiple variables and use them.

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:30),
                  child:RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context, titleController.text); //i want to pass multiple controllers here
                      print(titleController.text);

                    },
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                  ),
                ),
```

**Use:**
here is how i am using returned data. it's working fine for one text field but i want multiple fields passed.

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {

 final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );

              varlistSection.insert(0,
            listSectionMethod("$result", "hello from click", Icons.forward), //result contains one text field data, i want to use it for more
          );
          setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Just pass a list of all the controllers' texts.

Comment: then how i can use them, i tried to make variable result[] to contain array, but  it was wrong

Comment: Just use a `for` loop to get all the texts.

Comment: how i can do that, i think there should be other solution aswell

Comment: @Fayakon, Benjamin is right. Just return list from your second page. How to use your retrieved list depends on what you're doing. How are you planning to display the data in your first page?

Comment: i want to use it here, listSectionMethod("$result", "data of text field 2", Icons.forward),

Comment: In that case you can just use `listSectionMethod("$result", result[index], Icons.forward)`, depending on which data you wanna use from the list.

Comment: by passing like this from other screen? Navigator.pop(context, [titleController.text,detailController.text]); it writes it in one line instead of considering it another index.

Comment: @Fayakon, check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fayakon, what you've done for one variable looks good. Try returning a String list from your second page when you pop it like so,

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.add(titleController.text);
list.add(detailController.text);
Navigator.pop(context, list);
```

Then use it in your first page's function,

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {

 final result = await Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );

 varlistSection.insert(0,
            listSectionMethod(result[0], result[1], Icons.forward), //index would be for the data you wanna use
          );
 setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: i tried listSectionMethod("$result", "$result[1]", Icons.forward), and i am getting both of them in one line with [1], $result[1] is string type for method where i am passing it. if i type hard core value like,  listSectionMethod("title", "detail", Icons.forward) it will show title on top and description bottom, but when i used $result with index from your code, everything is in one line.

Comment: got it; listSectionMethod(result[0], result[1], Icons.forward),

Comment: Okay, i didn't know what you were using but glad it helped. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: 
false));
 }
```

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

```
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> key = GlobalKey();
 GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<String> _items = [];

   Future<String> showInfoDialog(BuildContext) async {
   return await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      final TextEditingController _textTitleController =
          TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _textDiscriptionController =
          TextEditingController();
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Form(
            key: _formkey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _textTitleController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    return value.isEmpty ? "Invalid Field" : null;
                  },
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Report Title"),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _textDiscriptionController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    return value.isEmpty ? "Invalid Field" : null;
                  },
                  decoration:
                      InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Report 
        Discrption"),
                )
              ],
            )),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
              child: Text('submit'),
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .pop(_textTitleController.text.toString());
                }
              })
        ],
      );
    });
  }

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Alert'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
        elevation: 2,
      ),
      body: AnimatedList(
        key: key,
        initialItemCount: _items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
          return _buildItem(
            _items[index],
            animation,
            index,
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          await showInfoDialog(context).then((value) {
            int i = _items.length > 0 ? _items.length : 0;
            _items.insert(i, value);
            key.currentState.insertItem(i);
          });
        },
      ),
    ));
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String items, Animation animation, int index) {
  return SizeTransition(
  sizeFactor: animation,
  child: Card(
    elevation: 2,
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(
        items,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
      ),
      subtitle: Text("crush report in the main road"),
      leading: const Icon(
        Icons.warning_rounded,
        color: Colors.red,
        size: 30,
      ),

      // CircleAvatar(
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      // ),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _removeItem(index);
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

void _removeItem(int i) {
String removedItem = _items.removeAt(i);
AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (
  context,
  animation,
) {
  return _buildItem(removedItem, animation, i);
};
key.currentState.removeItem(i, builder);
}

}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a bunch of code. Instead, try to explain _what_ your code is doing, and _why_ this solves the problem. Keep in mind that many readers will be new to Flutter, so helping them understand the concepts will make this a more useful answer. While you're at it, please fix your code formatting.